# Will resizing UITableViewCell automatically resize its contentView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

It seems that the autoresize flag in contentView is set to false. So basically the contentView autoresize flag looks like this:

[image]

Note: I did some tests and yes, contentView automatically got resized when the cell it self is resized. However, why the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth flag is disabled is beyond me because contentView behaves exactly as if UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth flag is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

**YES.**

UITableViewCell's contentView is readonly property. It is being manipulated by Apple in  UITableViewCell class.

Even in IB you can't set/Customize the

```
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

It was disabled.

So it will be handled by Apple. So it will resize the contentView based on the table View editing action....

Refer the attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll select this latter. I updated the question a little bit and may be someone could explain why contentView behaves as if UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth is enabled even though it's disabled